# Ayuda en recursion Java:

Tags: recursión

Tengo el siguiente codigo pero requiero pasarlo a forma recursiva:

```
 public static void agregarAuxiliarPalabras(String matriz[][], ArrayList<String> al, int a, int b) {
    String aux = "";

    // if(a>matriz.length){
    // return matriz;
    // }

    while (a < matriz.length) {

        aux = matriz[a][b];
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Palabra:" + aux);
        if (b == matriz[0].length - 1) {
            a++;
            b = 0;

        } else {
            b++;

        }

    }

}
```

Intente hacerlo y este fue el resultado:

```
 public static ArrayList<String> agregarAuxiliarPalabras_Recursivo(String matriz[][], ArrayList<String> al, int a, int b) {

    String aux = "";

    if (a <= matriz.length) {

        if (b > matriz[0].length - 1) {
            // System.out.println(j);
            b = 0;
            return agregarAuxiliarPalabras_Recursivo(matriz, al, a++, b);

        } else {

            aux = matriz[a][b];
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Palabra:" + aux);
            return agregarAuxiliarPalabras_Recursivo(matriz, al, a, b++);
        }
    }

    return al;
}
```

El problema radica en que al momento de correrlo claramente ahi un probema y solo imprimime la primera palabra ingresada, sera quizas un error en alguna condicion o instruccion de IF-ELSE ?, Gracias...

Comment: El parámetro `ArrayList<String> al` no se usa?

Comment: No, solo quiero llamar por decirlo asi al metodo en el main para otra cuestion, pero eso implica no retornar en ese caso no seria el parametro de ArrayList si no cual...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


   String[][] arreglo = new String[2][2];
        arreglo[0][0] = "hola";
        arreglo[0][1] = "adios";
        arreglo[1][0] = "texto";
        arreglo[1][1] = "otro texto";


  String texto = agregarAuxiliarPalabras_Recursivo(arreglo, null, 0, 0);
        System.out.println(texto);
    }

    public static String agregarAuxiliarPalabras_Recursivo(String matriz[][], ArrayList<String> al, int a, int b) {

    //caso base se terminó de recorrer las columnas del arreglo, retorna ""
    if(a == matriz.length)return "";

    //si b es el ultimo elemento de la columna
    if(b == matriz[a].length -1)
    {
        //se obtiene la palabra de la posicion [a][b]
        String palabraActual = matriz[a][b];
        //reiniciar b  =  0 y a = a + 1

        String palabraSiguiente = 
                 //se avanza a la siguiente columna con a = a + 1 en la primera posición
                 //con b = 0
                agregarAuxiliarPalabras_Recursivo(matriz, al, a + 1 , 0);

        return palabraActual + "," + palabraSiguiente;

    }

    //casos recursivos

    //retornar palabra en posición [a] [b] + palabra en posicicion [a][b+1]
    String palabraActual = matriz[a][b];
    String palabraSiguiente = agregarAuxiliarPalabras_Recursivo(matriz, al, a , b + 1);

   return palabraActual + "," + palabraSiguiente;


}
```

Comment: Hola crrlos, deberías editar la respuesta para añadir más detalles y una descripción de lo que has hecho y cómo soluciona el problema. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Lee [answer] para más información.